# How to translate MultiSelect Option Set Options?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I've created a MultiSelect Option Set field in the case entity with multiple options. My D365 environment has 3 languages set up and I want to translate those options for these languages.
When I export translations in D365, I cannot find these options in the Excel file. I've tried using Toolbox Easy Translator as well without success.

Also, I couldn't find any documentation saying this was a limitation.

Comment: Are you not getting any optionset labels or only specific custom picklist labels? Any clue like global picklist or custom or multi select only?

Comment: @ArunVinoth I can translate the multi-option set field label, but not its options labels. It is a custom multi option set field, single option set fields are translated fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have use Easy Translator and 2 of the spreed sheets are "Global OptionSets" and "OptionSets" and includes the column for the Language (spanish in the images), in the example I have selected the phonecall entity and select all the options

Hope it helps

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the option set values directly to your multi-select field.

Instead create a new option set first (below the node 'option sets' in your solution), and add your values there.

When creating your multi-select field, choose the option to use an existing option set, and select the one you created before.

Now when you export the translations all your option set values should be available for translation.